# Django reading model data in a template

Tags: database, django, templates

I'm new to django and am having trouble reading data from a model in a template.

Here's the model.

```
class Team(models.Model):
team_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="Team")
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.team_name
```

The view.

```
def create_team(request):
team = Team.objects.all()
return render_to_response("ideas/profile.html", {'team':team})
```

And the template.

```
<h2>Available groups: {{team.team_name}} </h2>
```

Likelihood this is an obvious fix: 99%. Thanks anyway guys!

Comment: Are you sure you posted enough of your template? I'm missing a loop here. edit: I guess that was the problem ;-) Go for Chris Pratt's answer, it's full of good advice.

Answer (score 2):

`team` is not an object, it's a queryset -- simplistically, a *list* of objects. Even if there's only one object in the table, it's simply a list of one. As a result, you can't just reference model attributes on it as if it were an instance of the model -- you have to pull the instance out first:

```
{% for t in team %}
    {{ t.team_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

A couple of notes. As the loop shows, naming it `team` doesn't make sense. That implies one thing, and now we're going to loop through a single entity? Best practice here is to name single items singular and querysets, lists, etc. plural. Then we would do `for team in teams` which makes *a lot* more sense.

Secondly, don't use the model name in the attribute name. `team.team_name` is redundant, when `team.name` would work just as well. If there's *another* "name" attribute, then prefix that one, but the model itself should have priority on top-level attribute names.

Comment: Thanks @chris! So, would you revise the model to be "teams" or the variable within the view to be "teams"?

Comment: Sorry, no, model names should be singular, pretty much always. It's a description of thing, not a group of things. The point I was making is this: `team = Team.objects.get(pk=1)`, `teams = Team.objects.all()`.

Comment: Thanks @chris! For future readers, I revised the model to `class Teams(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="CW Team")
 created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

 def __unicode__(self):
  return self.name` The view to: `def profile(request,
             template_name='profile.html'):
    teams = Teams.objects.all()
    return render_to_response(template_name, {'teams': teams}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))` And the html to:   `<h2>Available teams: 
  {% for t in teams %}
      {{ t.name }},
  {% endfor %} 
 </h2>`

Comment: Since the example model includes ´__unicode__´ that returns the team_name a simplification could be to use {{ t }}.